# Uniqueness of a pseudoinverse which is not a Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

> **Definition** Let $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ be a matrix. Then a matrix $B 
>  \in M_{n,m}(\mathbb{R})$ is called a **pseudoinverse** of $A$ if we
>   have
>
> 1. $ABA = A$ and
> 2. $BAB = B$.
>
> If in addition
>
> 3. $AB$ and $BA$ are symmetric
>
> then we call $B$ a **Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse**.

In the literature, one shows that every matrix $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ has a **unique** Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $A^+$.

**My question**: Does the uniqueness still hold if we omit condition 3., i.e. $B$ is a pseudoinverse which is not a Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, if you drop the symmetry condition you might get infinitely many solutions. Take
$$ A=\begin{pmatrix} 1& 0\\ 0 &0\end{pmatrix}, \qquad B=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c& d \end{pmatrix}$$
You compute that $ABA=A$ is equivalent to $a=1$ and that
$$ ABA=A, \ BAB=B \qquad \text{iff} \qquad bc=d.$$
Hence, there are infinitely many pseudoinverses which are not Moore-Penrose pseudo inverses.